# Need some reference articles for sample size determination in clinical trials

Tags: sampling, sample-size

I'm working with some clinical trial study. So I need some articles for determination of sample size in different types of clinical studies. I already have googled it. If anyone expertise in this field can suggest me some artiles that will very helpful.

Comment: This question would be better suited to the Stack Exchange math or stats site.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do this.